Set default permission with syncthing
Using syncthing our smartphone images and videos sync

automatically and
wirelessly

peer-to-peer to a desktop PC. This enables new content to be reviewed on the pc and duplicate scene shots deleted on the phones - all without messing with wires.  MiniDLNA streams all family media to the TV. For streaming to the TV, permissions need to be set on the new media created by syncthing to allow read access for other.  How do I set the default on that desktop sync folder.

setfacl -R -d -m o::r-- FolderPath

